# Combining "NOT" and "AND" in SQL (MS Access specifically)

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a quick question please. I am trying to write a query that combines "NOT" and "AND" in MS access. But for some reason I am not getting the correct result. For example, if i have a table:

```
ID| Name1| Name2|  
1 | a    | a    |  
2 | b    | b    |  
3 | a    |      |  
4 |      | a    |  
5 | a    | b    |  
6 | b    | a    |
```

What i want from my query is everything from name1 and name 2 that isn't b,b so all the IDs except 2. but i can only see ID - 1 which is a,a.

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE Names
WHERE NOT Name1 = 'b' AND NOT Name2 = 'b'
```

which only returns ID 1.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: And you also want ids 3 and 4 in the result? (google for "three valued logic" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding the NULLs by only using equality testing, applying deMorgan's laws:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Names 
WHERE NOT (Name1 = 'b' AND Name2 = 'b')
 ;
```

The idea is: conditions with `NULL` values never test true: `NULL = 'x'` is false, and `NULL <> 'x'` also is false. (even `NULL = NULL` is false!)

In short: the condition `(Name1 = 'b' AND Name2 = 'b')` is only true for the row with `id=2`; by applying NOT to this condition you get all rows EXCEPT id=2.

Comment: `NULL = 'x'` returns Null.  `NULL <> 'x'` returns Null.  `NULL = NULL` returns Null.

Comment: ... which doesn't evaluate to true, that was my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to help break up bits of logic, and prefer `<>` over `NOT`

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE Names 
WHERE (Name1 <> 'b') OR (Name2 <> 'b')
```

You may have to coerce null values to get 3 and 4:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE Names 
WHERE (NZ(Name1, "") <> 'b') OR (NZ(Name2, "") <> 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Null values should be compared separately or converted to string:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE Names WHERE NOT (Nz(Name1,'') = 'b') AND NOT (Nz(Name2,'') = 'b')
```